# Ruby get UDPSocket port number

Tags: ruby, sockets, udp

I am trying get the port number after I have bind my UDPSocket to a free port number. so

`udp_server = UDPSocket.new`

`udp_server.bind('localhost', 0)`

So I am passing a 0 here to let udp_server randomly pick a free port number for me.

Is it possible to get the port number after doing the bind?  Say something like

`udp_server.get_port_number`

I have searched online but didn't find a solution.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
udp_server.addr[1]
```